# Magmi Generic mapper does not work on Create, only works on Update

Tags: magento, csv, magmi

I installed Magmi (v0.7.21) on Magento 1.8.1, enabled Generic mapper v0.0.6a for status and visibility purposes to remap to numeric values.

But when I run the import in mode "create new items only, skip existing ones" it does NOT seem to be working - all items are set to Catalog, Search and Enabled.

It only works when I rerun the same file in "Update existing items only" mode then it will update the values based on the csv files.

The csv files used are in dir /magmi/plugins/base/itemprocessors/genericmapper/mappings folder.

How can i make it work in "create new items only" mode?

Comment: Anybody? this is driving me crazy all day...